# Not able getting data from database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

connect.php :

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'cms');
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    die('Sorry, We are having some problems');
}

function escape($string){
    return htmlentities($string,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
}

?>
```

printdata.php :

```
<?php 
require 'include/connect.php';
$cerid = escape($_POST['cerid']);
$student = escape($_POST['student']);

if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM certificate WHERE name = {$student} ")){
    if ($result->num_rows) {
        $rows =$result->fetch_assoc();
        echo $rows['cerid'];
        echo "<br>  {$rows['name']} ";
        echo $rows['cname'];
        echo $rows['dname'];
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: Most likely a scope issue.

Comment: Well, firstly what issue are you having? You haven't even asked a question. Is your connection okay? Have you debugged? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: when i used $cerid in the place of $student that worked.... but now

Comment: Then check your form elements so that they all contain the name attribute.

Comment: #Lee there was not any error displayed.....

Comment: By the way, if you're using `htmlentities` to "escape" data in order to prevent injection, then you're going about it the wrong way. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: #Fred  I also checked that by echo this on printdata.php page...

Comment: Pass DB connection to your function.

Comment: Are both values `int` or is one of them a string?

Comment: student is a string......

Comment: There we have it. See Jeroen's answer below. You need to quote strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You are not quoting your values. When you don't use a prepared statement (recommended...) you should quote them;
2. You have a potential sql injection problem. `htmlentities()` does not protect you from that.

It should be something like:

```
function escape($string, $mysqli){
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $string);
    // or
    return $mysqli->real_escape_string($string);
}
```

calling your function like:

```
$cerid = escape($db, $_POST['cerid']);
// etc.
```

and:

```
if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM certificate WHERE name = '{$student}' ")){
```

Although a prepared statement would save you the trouble of escaping your values.

Comment: There we have it. `int`s and strings being *two different animals* altogether ;-)